# Как поочередно открыть все файлы в каталоге .bat скриптом, находящимся в этом же каталоге

Tags: windows, bat

Уважаемые программисты, к помощи вашей взыщу.
Имеется каталог с большим количеством файлов .mpg, в каталоге так же имеется программа.exe.
Нужно с помощью программы.exe открыть все файлы .mpg внутри каталога, поочередно с паузой в 300 сек. (по умолчанию файлы .mpg открываются плеером)
Подозреваю, что можно это сделать bat скриптом, но познаний не хватает, чтобы сложить этот пазл.

Comment: [Добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/664589/edit) метку - Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bat:

```
for %%f in (*.mpg) do cscript script.js %%f
```

где script.js:

```
var wss = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var cmd = "программа.exe " + WScript.Arguments(0);
wss.Exec(cmd);
WScript.sleep(300000);
```

Comment: сделал bat -

` for %%f in (*.mpg) do cscript script.js %%f  ` 
 и  script.js - 

`программа.exe WScript.Arguments(1)
WScript.sleep(300000);` 

пишет

 Ошибка компиляции Microsoft jscript: предполагается наличие ';'

Comment: да после .Arguments(1) надо поставить ;

Comment: поставил  ; после .Arguments(1), все тоже самое пишет

Ошибка компиляции Microsoft jscript: предполагается наличие ';'

Comment: да ошибся, вот так надо

Comment: Спасибо, работает.
не так, как ожидалось, но работает.
странно, но файл .mpg не обработался программой.exe,

Comment: можно поставить вместо "cscript script.js" программа.exe, но bat не умеет задержки делать и может в командной строке программы нужны какие-то ключи?

Comment: Огромное спасибо.
"вместо "cscript script.js" программа.exe," работает, да без задержки.
но работает..

Comment: еще более огромное спасибо. с задержками тоже работает.